# FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions. even if firestore rules read and write are permitted - Angular-Fire

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

i've got this problem when calling firestore function from angular fire.
When i'm succesfully authenticated, i'm fetching to firestore the current user document id for additional data associated with the user.

```js
 // In App.Component
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.afAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        // Some firestore call like
        // let p: QuerySnapshot<AppUser> = await this.firestore.collection<AppUser>('users').ref.where('uid', '==', 'myuserid').get(); 
        // --> FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.
       }
    });
  }
```

I don't understand because my rules for firestore are :

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

so read and write are permitted to everyone.

I'm facing this error since i've enforced security as firebase console "AppCheck" suggested, now, as far as i remember, only specific applications are accepted and i've settled recaptcha, so is this occuring because recaptcha configuration is missing in my app ? Or maybe it's not related ? https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/recaptcha-provider

Comment: I've settled Recaptcha for my website but i still get this error : FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions. :(

Answer (score 0):

Following these steps made things works :

- Read Recaptcha Provider https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/recaptcha-provider
- Create Recaptcha Site on Recaptcha Admin
- Add ng-recaptcha to the project, follow instructions to accordingly modify app module
- Read Debug Provider https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/debug-provider
- Add Debug Token to App Check

So the rules were not sufficient, a correct configuration of AppCheck was required in my case